# MYSQL. Need logical operator like and

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators

For where clause I need operator like and (&). It adds to result set if all bits in int field is on. &-operator not always returns right answer.

Examples:
1.
Conts = 132. (128+4)
Database field 160. (128+32)
Mysql & operator return true. But I need it return true if only 128 bit and 4 bit set (for example for 196(128+64+4).

1. Conts = 128
   Database field 160. Mysql &-operator returns true, and its ok.
2. Conts = 220(4+8+16+64+128).
   Databse field = 40 (32+8). Mysql &-operator returns true. It's no ok, because in 220 presents only 8 bit.

Comment: `&` is bit-wise AND, it's not a logical operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `conts & field`, it will be true if *any* of the bits in `conts` are set in `field`. To tell if *all* the bits in `conts` are on in the database field, use:

```
conts & field = conts
```

Examples:

```
+-----------------+
| 132 & 160 = 132 |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
| 132 & 196 = 132 |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
| 128 & 160 = 128 |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
+-----------------+
+----------------+
| 220 & 40 = 220 |
+----------------+
|              0 |
+----------------+
```

Comment: maybe I am wrong in my interpretation of the question but it seems this will not help in the first example. By the way my solution also does not work for it.

Comment: See my examples, I get the desired answer for all his examples.

Comment: I see you are correct. I did not understand correctly what is the desired output for 132 and 160

Comment: Yes, his first example is a little confusing, you have to read between the lines.